# How to mirror an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

A mirrored array looks like this.

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
let mirrored = [1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1]
```

Please help me achieve the result.

Comment: not really mirrored ... the `5` is in the result only once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to achieve the intended result like this.

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
let x = [...arr];
let result =  x.concat(arr.reverse().slice(1,arr.length));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: With a bit of ESNext sugar -> `[...arr,...arr.slice(0,-1).reverse()]`

Comment: Not sure what you mean confused, and I didn't downvote.